# Keyboard actions in Selenium Grid ( Remote Web Driver )

Tags: selenium-grid

I've been working on automating tasks with Selenium, and I've encountered a challenge when attempting to use keyboard actions in Selenium Grid. Initially, I utilized the Robot class in Java, which worked seamlessly in my local Selenium WebDriver setup. However, when I tried running the same code in Selenium Grid, the keyboard actions didn't function as expected.

I've been exploring potential solutions and came across mentions of Robotil. Some users suggested that it might address my issue, but I'm unsure about how to proceed or whether it's the right approach for my problem.

To provide a bit more context, I'm trying to set up a keyboard shortcut (Ctrl + Shift + Y) for a Chrome extension. This shortcut is crucial as it triggers a popup extension that relies on the base site. Essentially, I'm aiming to automate the process of opening this extension using Selenium.

Any insights or suggestions on how to tackle this issue in Selenium Grid would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: /***********************###**************************/
output
robotKeyPress
robotKeyPress:17
Server is not reachable... IP[http://172.18.0.3] Port[5555]
robotKeyPress:16
Server is not reachable... IP[http://172.18.0.3] Port[5555]
robotKeyPress:89
Server is not reachable... IP[http://172.18.0.3] Port[5555]
open extention entered short cut
Server is not reachable... IP[http://172.18.0.3] Port[5555]
robotKeyrelease:17
Server is not reachable... IP[http://172.18.0.3] Port[5555]
robotKeyrelease:16
Server is not reachable... IP[http://172.18.0.3] Port[5555]
robotKeyrelease:89`